# DIV tag equivalent in Qt Graphics Framework

Tags: qt, pyside

I am working on a simple desktop application where I have to show a tree structure of folders and files along with other diagrams. For this I chose Qt and python (PySide). I need a structure like below (Forgive me for the bad drawing. But you get the idea):[image]

The folders can be double clicked to expand/shrink. When a folder expands, new child elements need to take more space, and the folders below the current folder must move down. Similarly when the folder is shrunk, the folders below the current folder must come up; just like a standard folder system.

Hence I am in search of a `<div>` equivalent element in Qt where I can place each directory and all of its children inside that div and the div can expand and shrink. This way I don't have to write code for a re-draw every time the folder is opened/closed. Currently I have to calculate each item's position and place the child items respective to that position. That is a lot of calculation and no of items are > 1000. `With a div, I will just re-calculate positions of child items and resize the div. Other divs can then automatically re-draw themselves.`

I am not using QTreeView because as I said earlier, I have to draw other diagrams and connect these folders with them. QTreeView will live in its own space (with scroll bar and stuff), and I won't be able to draw lines to connect items in QTreeView and QGraphicsScene.

You can view my current work [here](https://github.com/rash805115/twig) in github. [Here is the file that has my work.](https://github.com/rash805115/twig/blob/master/twig/guicomponents/directory.py)

Comment: Hi @Mat I cannot use tree view because as I said in my question, I need to draw additional lines to connect my folders and other drawings in QGraphicsScene. A tree view does not allow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're thinking of "`<div>`". It's just the most simple HTML container, and it seems to have nothing to do with your goal.

You can use graphics layouts to align items in the scene automatically. Here's how it can be implemented:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Leaf(QtGui.QGraphicsProxyWidget):
  def __init__(self, path, folder = None):
    QtGui.QGraphicsProxyWidget.__init__(self)
    self.folder = folder
    label = QtGui.QLabel()
    label.setText(QtCore.QFileInfo(path).fileName())
    self.setWidget(label)
    self.setToolTip(path)
    self.setAcceptedMouseButtons(QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)

  def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if self.folder:
      self.folder.toggleChildren()

class Folder(QtGui.QGraphicsWidget):
  def __init__(self, path, isTopLevel = False):
    QtGui.QGraphicsWidget.__init__(self)
    self.offset = 32
    childrenLayout = QtGui.QGraphicsLinearLayout(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
    childrenLayout.setContentsMargins(self.offset, 0, 0, 0)

    flags = QtCore.QDir.AllEntries | QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot
    for info in QtCore.QDir(path).entryInfoList(flags):
      if info.isDir():
        childrenLayout.addItem(Folder(info.filePath()))
      else:
        childrenLayout.addItem(Leaf(info.filePath()))

    self.childrenWidget = QtGui.QGraphicsWidget()
    self.childrenWidget.setLayout(childrenLayout)

    mainLayout = QtGui.QGraphicsLinearLayout(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
    mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.leaf = Leaf(path, self)
    mainLayout.addItem(self.leaf)
    mainLayout.addItem(self.childrenWidget)
    if isTopLevel:
      mainLayout.addStretch()
    self.setLayout(mainLayout)

  def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
    QtGui.QGraphicsWidget.paint(self, painter, option, widget)
    if self.childrenWidget.isVisible() and self.childrenWidget.layout().count() > 0:
      lastChild = self.childrenWidget.layout().itemAt(self.childrenWidget.layout().count() - 1)
      lastChildY = self.childrenWidget.geometry().top() + \
          lastChild.geometry().top() + self.leaf.geometry().height() / 2;
      painter.drawLine(self.offset / 2, self.leaf.geometry().bottom(), self.offset / 2, lastChildY)
      for i in range(0, self.childrenWidget.layout().count()):
        child = self.childrenWidget.layout().itemAt(i)
        childY = self.childrenWidget.geometry().top() + \
            child.geometry().top() + self.leaf.geometry().height() / 2
        painter.drawLine(self.offset / 2, childY, self.offset, childY)

  def toggleChildren(self):
    if self.childrenWidget.isVisible():
      self.layout().removeItem(self.childrenWidget)
      self.childrenWidget.hide()
      self.leaf.widget().setStyleSheet("QLabel { color : blue; }")
      print "hide"
    else:
      self.childrenWidget.show()
      self.layout().insertItem(1, self.childrenWidget)
      self.leaf.widget().setStyleSheet("")
    self.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
    view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene)
    # put your root path here
    scene.addItem(Folder("/usr/share/alsa", True))
    view.show()
    view.resize(400, 400)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Hi @Pavel thanks for the solution. I am trying to understand your code, but when I run it on my system, many parts dont work. Connecting lines are not drawn and no mouse press event is being captured. Also nothing is shown in blue as indicated by stylesheet. I tried but cannot make it work. What is your PySide version ? Once I understand the code, I can explain more clearly what I want and whether or not this is the solution. But thanks again.

Comment: I use PySide 1.1.1 based on Qt 4.8.2. OS is Debian.

Comment: it works perfectly in windows, not in mac...both OS has pyside 1.2.2 and Qt 4.8.6

Comment: This can easily be a bug in either Qt or PyQt. I encountered strange behavior multiple times while I wrote this code, and I had to choose the variant that worked correctly on my system. I don't have Mac and can't help you with your issues, but you can try to modify the implementation and find a working approach. For example, you can paint all tree lines to `QPainterPath` and use `QGraphicsScene::addPath` to draw it, and you can use `QGraphicsScene::​mousePressEvent` to capture events globally.

Comment: Hi. Sorry it took me a while to figure it out since I just started GUI programming. I understood everything except these: 1. Why the proxy widget. The docs dont explain clearly the purpose of this class. 2. Instead of just text, I inserted some images. But I cannot show text and image simultaneously in QLabel. Only one of them is shown. How do I show both of them side by side.

Comment: Also when I asked the original question, I did not know about these classes. I was working with only scene, view and graphicitems. I was trying to completely simulate the drawing and re-positioning of elements if folders are hidden/shown. Hence a div like element was needed which can hold a directory and its contents in a block which can be hidden and shown as needed. Your answer allows me to do just that because as I understand now, you can use the QGraphWidgets and QGraphLayout to keep elements in batch. Also layout takes care of positioning. Awesome answer. Many Many Thanks !!

Comment: Proxy widget allows to put any QWidget in a graphics scene. I couldn't use `QGraphicsTextItem` because I needed something that inherits `QGraphicsLayoutItem`. So you can create a subclass of `QGraphicsLayoutItem` or `QGraphicsWidget`, reimplement all required virtual functions and get the look and behavior you need. Another option is to work with proxy widget: create a QWidget, add a layout to it, add two labels to the layout, add the widget to proxy widget.